# CSS margin collapse... not happening?

Tags: css, margin

I just started with CSS.... I was meddling with the code that you can find here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_clear

The margin collapse to my understanding is margin that is greater of the two margins(vertical)
but in this case the bottom margin between the .text_line and the images becomes 2px instead of 5px, which is lesser of the two margins, why is that?

in the .text_line, if you remove-

margin-bottom:2px;

then the margin becomes 5px which is normal.

I thought the "clear:both;" had something to do with it but removing only the clear property also gives a 2px margin and not 5px.

Why???

heres the code, if you don't want to visit the link...

```
 .thumbnail 
{
float:left;
width:110px;
height:90px;
margin:5px;
}
.text_line
{
clear:both;
margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

class thumbnail is for images and text_line is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 2px, it's 7px. You can see this if you set the background color to .text_line. Margins of floated boxes don't collapse according to [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) (see the 2nd Note).

Comment: but then why is the margin increasing when you remove the margin in the text_line?

Comment: It's because of the default margins of the <h3> element. In most browsers' built-in default styles the top and bottom margins ot this element are equal to its font-size (1em).

Answer (score 0):

The margins are not collapsing. When you disabled `margin-bottom`, what you're really seeing happen is the margin go back to the *browser default*, which (for me) is much larger than then 2px originally given.

If you add `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to the top of the CSS, you should see behavior closer to what you're expecting.

Try using [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), which will let you selectively disable styles. It should help you see what is actually going on with the margins.